# remove unsafe-eval from CSP header

Tags: javascript

I have very old javascript code and in that code they are using unsafe-eval but now client is saying we have to remove unsafe-eval but in my code in all the java script library is using eval method and code is not working after removing unsafe-eval,how i can remove unsafe-eval without changing the lib code.

so which version i can use that will not give me nonce error.
currently i am using 2.0.2
and getting below error.
[image]

zone.min.js?_=1686053845269:1 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-/jHqQHDI76+2UJhy0y0afg=='".

```
at new Function (<anonymous>)
at evalExpression (compiler.umd.min.js?_=1686053845269:6:1473)
at jitStatements (compiler.umd.min.js?_=1686053845269:21:30062)
at RuntimeCompiler._compileModule (compiler.umd.min.js?_=1686053845269:41:18413)
at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.umd.min.js?_=1686053845269:41:16590)
at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.umd.min.js?_=1686053845269:41:16063)
at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (core.umd.min.js?_=1686053845269:35:26523)
at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (core.umd.min.js?_=1686053845269:35:25813)
at Object.initAngularComponents (consentRegistry.js?_=1686053845270:415:47)
at Object.init (consentRegistry.js?_=1686053845270:63:22)
```

Comment: Re edit: You aren't getting a nonce-related error. You're getting an unsafe-eval related error.

Comment: yes but how i can resolve this error

Comment: I refer you to my earlier answer. Stop using the library.

Comment: return (new (Function.bind.apply(Function, [void 0].concat(fnArgNames.concat(fnBody))))).apply(void 0, fnArgValues) This line is throwing the error is there another way to implement this line.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

1. The client requires that you do not allow `unsafe-eval`
2. You have a library which will not work unless you allow `unsafe-eval`
3. You cannot change the source code of that library

The only approach to have working code which is compatible with all three conditions is to **stop using the library and rewrite any code you have which depends on it**.